# Is one type of options to ps preferred?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ps

GNU `ps` supports BSD-style options, UNIX-style options, and GNU long options. Is using one of these types (in scripts and at the command line) preferred over the others?

I get the impression from the manpage that the functionality of the option styles does not overlap completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking just use the set of options that gives you the results you want.

For the sake of (other people's) sanity & portability I suggest sticking with BSD-style or SysV-style arguments -- for the most part modern systems accept both of those argument sets, and that way when the script you wrote to solve a problem on Linux gets dropped onto a system that doesn't understand GNU-style long options it still works (all the world is **not** a Linux machine).

Answer (score 1):

> Is using one of these types (in
>   scripts and at the command line)
>   preferred over the others?

This largely depends on the target platforms your scripts should run on. If your scripts should run only on Linux go with the GNU-style options, if they should also be usable on *BSD go with the BSD-style options and last but not least if they should run on a wide range of unixoid systems (e. g. Solaris) go with the UNIX-style options.

Comment: Seriously? The GNU-style options are the long options.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html) says. I'm not up to stuff on this, but I would guess scripts using ps won't be very portable anyway.

Comment: +1 for "scripts using ps won't be very portable".

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the POSIX or SVR4 options are far more common.

I generally parse uname output, and select the correct /bin/ps, /usr/bin/ps and arguments based on that value.   On unsupported platforms, I just exit, I don't guess.  On linux, I set $PS_PERSONALITY to "posix" and unset $I_WANT_A_BROKEN_PS in case a user has that set for some reason.   This is just a defensive measure.

The GNU getopt_long() style is useful only on Linux, and even if that's what you're going for, people are far more familiar with the short options.